# Maintaining HTTP download link for Cocoapods Podspec source

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have an iOS framework that I would like to distribute through Cocoapods and am currently writing a PodSpec file for this framework library. The PodSpec file will be using an [HTTP source](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#source) to download a zip file containing the framework similar to this:

```
spec.source = { :http => 'http://dev.wechatapp.com/download/sdk/WeChat_SDK_iOS_en.zip' }
```

If I provide an http link to a zipped folder containing the SDK, will Cocoapods store a copy of the zip file in their service or does Cocoapods only hold the PodSpecs in their [Specs repository](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs) and provide the reference to the download link for every developer?

For example, I upload v1 of my framework to:

```
 http://somesource/library.zip
```

and use this link as my source in the PodSpec file. Then I upload v2 of my framework to the same source:

```
http://somesource/library.zip
```

can I use the same http source in the PodSpec file or am I required to maintain two separate download links for v1 and v2 of my library?

```
v1:
http://somesource/v1/library.zip

v2:
http://somesource/v2/library.zip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly advise to use versioned file download URLs, because else you won't be able to revert to previous versions (e.g. v1) later on.

Comment: Or to be more explicit: CocoaPods only hosts pod spec files, it doesn't keep copies of the downloads referenced in there. That's your job as the person who submits the podspec.